# Trouble converting from Clojure application to latest Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I can't figure out why I'm getting the following compile error after upgrading:

```
Compiling addr-verify.core
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
clojure/lang/ILookupHost, compiling:(core.clj:39:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3463)
```

I am using leiningen 2.3.4, and am trying to upgrade an application to use Clojure 1.5.1 and some dependencies. This compiled fine with the old project.clj. But I want to use the Clojure 1.5.1. I'm just confused as to what is causing this.

These are the differences between the two project.clj versions.

```
< (defproject addr-verify "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

> (defproject addr-verify "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

<   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
<                  [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
<                  [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.2.4"]
<                  [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
<                  [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
<    :main addr-verify.core)

>   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
>                  [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]
>                  [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.1"]
>                  [clj-http "0.9.1"]]
>    :omit-source true
>    :main addr-verify.core
>    :aot  [addr-verify.core])
```

Comment: Have you run `lein clean` since changing the versions? sometimes compiled artifacts are created and reused, and this can cause problems when you have version changes.

Comment: Please use this comment answer as a real answer. I have a new compilation problem now, which is a good sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `lein clean`, if you haven't yet.

Sometimes compiled artifacts are created and reused, and this can cause problems when you have library version changes. `lein clean` clears out those artifacts.

Comment: Thanks. This is what makes stackoverflow an invaluable resource. As long as someone doesn't throw up their hands and shows some work, people are willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

ILookupHost was removed as of Clojure 1.3.0, so perhaps you have an old compilation artifact or compiled dependency.

The most recent version of Clojure is 1.6.0 - why not upgrade to there instead?

I'm not sure what the differences are, but I usually use org.clojure/data.csv as my CSV library. Might be worth looking into.

If you need help finding old contrib, see: http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go